# Driver Hunting for a Wifi Card

Tags: laptop, drivers, wireless-networking

I had an older Toshiba Tecra A4 die recently. It was based on the Centrino chipset with the internal WIFI card. I pulled the WIFI card and put it in an Averatec 6200 series laptop. That one isn't a Centrino, but runs an AMD proc instead.

A fresh install of XP "sees" the card, but I've yet to hit the right driver combination to actually use it. I'm hoping someone here can give me a hand?

Details from the card:

```
Intel

FCC ID: CJ6UPA3362WL    
P/N: PA3362U-1MPC
Toshiba P/N: G86C0000X510
Toshiba Serial No: 7MY505233487
MFG Date: 01/25/05
PBA: C55369-011
```

There's another small sticker on it with the following:

```
KGF302J8RC36HJ
J5024  3.02
6042A00184T1
V000021020
```

**[Edit]**

Windows sees an unknown "Network Controller". That's what I'm *assuming* is this card. I could be wrong :-)  From the Details on that, here is some more info:

Hardware IDs:

```
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_4220&SUBSYS_27418086&REV05
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_4220&SUBSYS_27418086
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_4220&CC_028000
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_4220&CC_0280
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there's multiple references to that part number corresponding to an Intel PRO/Wireless 2200BG MiniPCI.  Here's the driver downloads for that @ Intel's site.

http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Product_Filter.aspx?ProductID=1637

Comment: Working around the one hyperlink per post limit for a new user...

If that's no good, here is the full set of drivers for the Tecra A4 from Toshiba's site.  One of those Intel Wireless drivers listed should be the one you're looking for.

http://www.csd.toshiba.com/cgi-bin/tais/support/jsp/modelContent.jsp?ct=DL&os=&category=&moid=882431&rpn=PTA40U&modelFilter=&selCategory=3&selFamily=1073768664

Comment: Download from the first link did the trick -- thanks!  I had tried a handful from toshiba but I guess I gave to soon up after kissing a couple frogs...